# Is it possible to pass the written citizenship test?

Tags: fallout-2

Is it possible to pass the written citizenship test for Vault 8/Vault City in Fallout 2?  What stats are required to pass it, if it is passable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(PE 9, IN 9 and LK 9)

> | It is possible to pass and become a citizen right away, but you need to boost the right stats **(PE 9, IN 9 and LK 9)**. The physical examination will disqualify you if you've grown extra toes in the Toxic Caves and didn't have them removed yet. You get 1000 xp if you pass the test.

Source: http://user.tninet.se/~jyg699a/fallout2.html

Comment: Ah I boosted my INT to 10 and didn't understand why I could not pass the test. Seems silly to me you also need luck and perception to 9 as well.

Comment: Well its 1000 EXP and you do not need it to get inside :)

Comment: @Halfwarr Vault City has a major superiority complex.  They may *say* there's a test you can take to become a citizen, but they don't really want you to pass.  It takes luck to deal with such an antagonistic test; it would almost certainly include a bunch of questions that require knowledge about Vault City's culture, and luck would be your only ally for those.

Comment: @ayckoster spoiler alert please! what if i didnt talk to the first citizen yet and didnt know that. Game ruined right there.